# Java : equals() and === on String and int variables

Tags: java, equals, equality-operator

I am trying to understand the equality (==) equals() method but couldn't reason out this behavior.
Can someone explain this behavior with the following println statements.

```
String a="Hai";
String b="Hai";
int c=5, d=5;

System.out.println("Check1 : " + (c==d)); //prints  "Check1 : true"

System.out.println("Check2 : " + a==b); //prints false. It didn't print the string "Check2 : "

System.out.println("Check3 : " +a.equals(b)); //prints "Check3 : true"

System.out.println(" c==d : " + c==d);   //compile time error - incomparable types: java.lang.String and int
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `a == b` prints `false`?

Answer (score 6):

It's because of orders of operations, in this part:

```
" c==d : " + c == d
```

There are no parenthesis, so the compiler goes:

```
(" c==d : " + c) == d
```

And you get an error because `string == int` is not defined. It's the same idea for the other example:

```
"Check2 : " + a == b → ("Check2 : " + a) == b → "Check2 : Hai" == "Hai" → false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parenthesis before doing the integer operation

Do in this way :

```
System.out.println(" c==d : " + (c==d));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain it one by one.

```
System.out.println("Check1 : " + (c==d));
```

This will print `true` as it is `int` comparison and both `c` as well as `d` has the same value.

```
System.out.println("Check2 : " + a==b);
```

It is printing `false` because concatenated String `Check2 :`  + `a` is not equals to String `b`. If you change `a==b` to `(a==b)` then it will start printing `true` as both `a` and `b` points to the same reference in the String Pool.

```
System.out.println("Check3 : " + a.equals(b));
```

This will print `true` because the content of String `a` is equal to the content of String `b`.

```
System.out.println(" c==d : " + c==d);
```

This will throw an error as it will be parsed as String `c==d` concatenated with `int c` converted to String (Because of Overload) is equal to `int d` and as you know we can't compare String with Integer and hence this will throw an error.